# How to extract a consecutive list of substring from a string?

Tags: string-manipulation

Given a list of strings:

```
data = {
 "2894;Hot Pink;53:09:44;1449714",
 "17456;Dark Cyan;19:06:42;6929227",
 "5147;Lime;54:11:55;5247632"
}
```

(Words are separated by `";"`, the number of words in strings are equal. Number of characters in strings are unequal. Number of characterss in words are unequal.)

How to extract the $m^{th}$ through $n^{th}$ words, so that e.g. $m=2, n=3$ should return:

```
{
"Hot Pink;53:09:44",
"Dark Cyan;19:06:42",
"Lime;54:11:55"
}
```

**UPDATE**

Final solution was found for the task.
I like to share it here.

```
inlist = RandomChoice[
{"7270;Deep Pink;04:14:55;0027354",
 "2871;Dark Orchid;54:21:23;1182263",
 "4021;Silver;04:00:58;6940040",
 "3521;Dark Slate Gray;18:42:43;5828275"}, 
400000];  

delim = ";";
fromWord = 2;
numberOfWords = 2;  

from = 2 fromWord - 1;
to = 2 (fromWord + numberOfWords - 1) - 1;
outlist = List /@ StringJoin /@
      StringSplit[inlist, delim -> delim][[All, from ;; to]]; // Timing  

{0.92, Null}
```

The honor goes to the very concerned in this task.
Every detail of their conception was vital to the solution.
Keep'n rocking.

Answer (score 6):

```
f[data_, from_, to_, sep_] := StringSplit[#, sep][[from ;; to]] & /@ data;
data = {"2894;Hot Pink;53:09:44;1449714", 
        "17456;Dark Cyan;19:06:42;6929227", 
        "5147;Lime;54:11:55;5247632"};

f[data, 2, 3, ";"]
(*
->{{"Hot Pink", "53:09:44"}, {"Dark Cyan", "19:06:42"}, {"Lime", "54:11:55"}}
*)
```

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi Of course I can't be sure, but my interpretation comes from the use of the word `through`in the OP's sentence `Give a list of strings containing chars m'th "Word"
through n'th "Word" in elements`

Comment: `StringSplit` is `Listable`.  Try: `f[data_, from_, to_, sep_] := 
 StringSplit[data, sep][[All, from ;; to]]`

Comment: Not quit what is expected.

Comment: Will say, not a result with  a 3 x 2 element list.  It should be a list of 3 elements.  The ";" sould be preserved.  hp

Comment: One could use `Take[]` instead of `Part[]`+`Span[]` of course...

Comment: @J.M. just read the OP's comment above yours ... "en fin"

Comment: Easily fixed with `StringJoin[]`, no?

Answer (score 4):

Specific case for $m=2$  and $n=3$:

```
data = {"2894;Hot Pink;53:09:44;1449714",
        "17456;Dark Cyan;19:06:42;6929227",
        "5147;Lime;54:11:55;5247632"};

First@StringCases[#, 
   StartOfString ~~ __ ~~ ";" ~~ x__ ~~ ";" ~~ y__ ~~ ";" :> x <> ";" <> y] & /@ data
```

> ```
> {"Hot Pink;53:09:44", "Dark Cyan;19:06:42", "Lime;54:11:55"}
> ```

More general version for any $m, n$:

```
{m, n} = {2, 3}

StringDrop[StringJoin@Drop[
    StringCases[#, Shortest[__ ~~ ";"], n], m - 1], -1] & /@ data
```

> ```
> {"Hot Pink;53:09:44", "Dark Cyan;19:06:42", "Lime;54:11:55"}
> ```

Comment: Your result gives a 3 x 2 list.  We need a list of 3 strings.       Hot Pink;53:09:44
Dark Cyan;19:06:42  
Lime;54:11:55    hp

Comment: @HP Please see edit. Nasser: I hope you don't mind that I added the general case to your answer instead of creating a new one. It fits in nicely I think. I you feel otherwise, please don't hesitate to roll back.

Comment: OK.   .   .Your function works well.  .  .It could not improve in timing compared to the algorithmic one shown below.

Comment: Have an other look. It seems not to get the last words.  .  .If you do {m, n}={1, 4}

Answer (score 1):

A solution was developed. 
Building a **program** working on two Streams.
One record by one record.

```
instr = OpenRead[infile];
outstr = OpenAppend[outfile];
azr=3; (* number of records to work on *)
abw=2; (* first word in record to extract *)
azw=2; (* number of words to extract *)
delim=";" (* separator char *)

Do[rean = Read[instr, "Record", NullWords -> True];
arean = rean <> delim;
pos = Flatten[StringPosition[arean, delim]];
fla = Flatten[{0, Drop[pos, {1, Length[pos], 2}]}];
extract = StringTake[arean, {fla[[abw]] + 1, fla[[abw + azw]] - 1}];
WriteString[outstr, extract, "\n"],
{i, azr}]; // Timing
```

It is a kind of ugly.
Could not find a function solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `StringExtract`:** (introduced March 30, 2015)

```
data = {"2894;Hot Pink;53:09:44;1449714", 
  "17456;Dark Cyan;19:06:42;6929227", "5147;Lime;54:11:55;5247632"}

StringExtract[#, ";" -> {2, 3}] & /@ data // Map[Riffle[#, ";"] &] // 
 Map[StringJoin]
```

or

```
StringExtract[#, ";" -> 2] <> ";" <> 
   StringExtract[#, ";" -> 3] & /@ data
```

---

*Result*

> {"Hot Pink;53:09:44", "Dark Cyan;19:06:42", "Lime;54:11:55"}